# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type generator)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having some problems with my code due to the `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type generator).` Error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

from tensorflow import keras

builder = tfds.builder('horses_or_humans')

ds_train = tfds.load(name = 'horses_or_humans', split = 'train')
ds_test = tfds.load(name = 'horses_or_humans', split = 'test')

train_images = np.array([example['image'].numpy()[:,:,0] for example in ds_train])
train_labels = np.array(example['label'].numpy() for example in ds_train)

test_images = np.array([example['image'].numpy()[:,:,0] for example in ds_test])
test_labels = np.array(example['label'].numpy() for example in ds_test)

train_images = train_images.reshape(1027, 300, 300, 1)

test_images = test_images.reshape(256, 300, 300, 1)
```

I've read that problem may appear here.

```
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')

train_images /= 255
test_images /= 255

model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
])

model.compile(
  optimizer = 'adam',
  loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
  metrics = ['accuracy']
              )

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32)
```

I've tried to do this

```
train_images = np.array(train_images).astype("float32")
test_images = np.array(test_images).astype("float32")
```

But sadly it's not working for me, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should read how to [load datasets via tfds](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example). You should not use NumPy in tensorflow processing pipeline when you can utilize native tensorflow operations.
2. Your neural network architecture doesn't fit the problem. There are examples of a [convolutional net](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-5-compleximages#4).

As for the code, it can be modified like so:

```
ds_train = tfds.load(name='horses_or_humans', split='train', as_supervised=True)
ds_test = tfds.load(name='horses_or_humans', split='test', as_supervised=True)

def normalize_img(image, label):
  """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
  return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label

ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.batch(32)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model.fit(ds_train, epochs=6)
```